# Hamburger bars on Vuetify in complex layout

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use **Vuetify 1.0.10**.

I want put *v-toolbar-side-icon* just beside slider/my name, above Dashboard title. But it is hidden by the navigation drawer where my name and first name.

I tried to add clipped and clipped-right but the orange headband come onto Dashboard toolbar.

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire" dark>

    <v-navigation-drawer
      left
      :mini-variant="miniVariant"
      v-model="drawerLeft"
      fixed
    >
       <!-- ... -->
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-card flat>
      <v-toolbar dark flat extended :color="dark ? 'dark' : 'orange'">
        <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawerLeft = !drawerLeft"/>
        <v-spacer/>
        <v-btn flat>
          <v-icon left>create</v-icon> <span class="hidden-md-and-down">Publish Something</span>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>
          <v-icon left>account_circle</v-icon> <span class="hidden-md-and-down">Profile</span>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-layout row pb-2>
        <v-flex xs8 offset-xs2>
          <v-card class="card--flex-toolbar">
            <nuxt/>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data: () => ({
      pageTitle: null,
    })
  }
</script>

<style>
  .card--flex-toolbar {
    margin-top: -64px;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or other where we can sse what you're trying to do ?